# Как отсортировать однолинейный список студентов по рейтингу? функция void sort

Tags: c++, сортировка, структуры, список

```
// вар16.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct student{
    char name[15], sname[15], pob[15], group[7];
    short int bal1, bal2, bal3;
    double serbal; student *next;
};
student *p, *pp, *head, *nov;
void stvor()
{
    p = new student;
    head = p;
    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        cout << "---Для окончания работы введите во все поля '0'---" << endl;
        cout << "----- Студент № " << i << " -----" << endl;
        pp = p;
        cout << "Введите фамилию: "; cin >> p->sname; cin.get();
        cout << "Введите имя: "; cin.getline(p->name, 15);
        cout << "Введите отчество: "; cin.getline(p->pob, 15);
        cout << "Введите групу (2букви-3цифры): "; cin.getline(p->group, 7);
        cout << "Введите оценку по математике: "; cin >> p->bal1;
        cout << "Введите оценку по програмированию: "; cin >> p->bal2;
        cout << "Введите оценку по английскому: "; cin >> p->bal3;
        p->next = new student;
        p = p->next;
        i++;
    } while ((pp->bal1 != 0) && ((pp->bal2 != 0) && (pp->bal3 != 0)));
    pp->next = NULL;
}
void srbal()
{
    p = head;
    while (p != 0)
    {
        p->serbal = (p->bal1 + p->bal2 + p->bal3) / 3;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
void print()
{
    p=head;
    cout << "Мы имеем такую информацию о студнентах: " << endl;
    cout << "№" << "\t" << "Имя" << "\t" << "Фамилия" << "\t" << "Отч-во" << "\t" << "Бал.Мат" << "\t" << "Бал.ПР" << "\t" << "Бал.англ" << "\t" << "Ср.бал" << endl;

    int i = 1;
    while (p != 0)
    {
        cout << i << "\t" << p->name << "\t" << p->sname << "\t" << p->pob << "\t" << p->bal1 << "\t" << p->bal2 << "\t"  << p->bal3 << "\t" << p->serbal << endl;
        p=p->next;
        i++;
    }

void sort()
{
    int m=0;
    head = p;

        while (p != 0)
        {
            pp = p;
            if (pp->serbal > p->serbal){
                m = pp->serbal;
                pp->serbal = p->serbal;
                p->serbal = m;

            }
            p = p->next;

        }

}

void del(student *head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        del(head->next); delete head;
    }

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    stvor();
    srbal();
    sort();
    print();

    del(head);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "OCP");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это уже у вас надо спрашивать, что именно вам надо реализовать. Списки, например, хорошо сортируются алгоритмом "merge sort"... Многие другие, более банальные методы сортировки тоже будут работать на списках. Или можно в конце концов тупо скопировать содержимое списка в массив, отсортировать и положить обратно.

Comment: @AnT причём вариант с копированием на практике может быть даже быстрее merge sort.